# Internet Explorer + Jquery Load = Logout user

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, session-cookies

I have a strange problem.
I am fixing a web page. In some pages jquery is loaded with the following line

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In Internet explorer, if I load a page that contains this line and then click somewhere else in the web page, it doesnt matter where, the user is logged out. It seems actually that this function is executed at last (PHP language is used)

```
function logout()
{
global $db;
session_start();

/* Delete the user from table online */
mysql_query("DELETE FROM online WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");

/* Update the table last seen in table users */
$date_now = date("Y-m-d");
$time_now = date("H:i");
$date_last_seen = $date_now. ' '. $time_now;

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET date_last_seen = '$date_last_seen'
WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
mysql_query("update `users` set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '' 
where `id`='$_SESSION[user_id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
}           

/************ Delete the sessions****************/
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

/* Delete the cookies*******************/
setcookie("user_id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_name", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

header("Location: index.php");
}
```

The session is destroyed, the user session is deleted from the database and the page is redirected to the index.php. 
If in the login page is selected "Remember me" in order to save a cookie then the page works properly.

In the 2 different pages that I load jquery I added this line on the top

```
<?php 
session_set_cookie_params(1800);
session_start();
?>
```

It saves the session cookie correctly but nothing happens at the end as the user is again logged out.

The jquery is loaded only in 2 pages to load when it is only needed. I tried to put it on the general header but the same problem takes place. When i removed the jquery line the page worked normal except of course the functions that needed it. So it's like a dead end.

I remind this happens only on IE (tested on IE 8 and IE 10). In the other browsers it works fine

This is the jquery code that it is supposed to be executed in one of the pages

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.2012_09_29.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>

<!-- Optionally include jquery.history.js for history support -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.history.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a#img_thumb').click(function() {
    var del_name=$(this).attr('href');
    del_name=del_name.replace('#','');
    $('input[id="delete_image"]').attr('value',del_name);
}); 
});
</scipt>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
            $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '96px', 'float' : 'right'});
            $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

            // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
            // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
            var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.80;
            $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li, div.navigation a.pageLink').opacityrollover({
                mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
                fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                exemptionSelector: '.selected'
            });

            // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
            var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                delay:                     1000,
                numThumbs:                 10,
                preloadAhead:              10,
                enableTopPager:            false,
                enableBottomPager:         false,
                imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
                controlsContainerSel:      '#controls',
                captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
                loadingContainerSel:       '#loading',
                renderSSControls:          true,
                renderNavControls:         true,
                playLinkText:              'Play Slideshow',
                pauseLinkText:             'Pause Slideshow',
                prevLinkText:              '&lsaquo; Previous Photo',
                nextLinkText:              'Next Photo &rsaquo;',
                nextPageLinkText:          'Next &rsaquo;',
                prevPageLinkText:          '&lsaquo; Prev',
                enableHistory:             true,
                autoStart:                 false,
                syncTransitions:           true,
                defaultTransitionDuration: 200,
                onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
                    // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
                    this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
                        .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
                        .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);

                    // Update the photo index display
                    this.$captionContainer.find('div.photo-index')
                        .html('Photo '+ (nextIndex+1) +' of '+ this.data.length);
                },
                onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
                    this.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, callback);
                },
                onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
                    var prevPageLink = this.find('a.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    var nextPageLink = this.find('a.next').css('visibility', 'hidden');

                    // Show appropriate next / prev page links
                    if (this.displayedPage > 0)
                        prevPageLink.css('visibility', 'visible');

                    var lastPage = this.getNumPages() - 1;
                    if (this.displayedPage < lastPage)
                        nextPageLink.css('visibility', 'visible');

                    this.fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                }
            });

            /**************** Event handlers for custom next / prev page links **********************/

            gallery.find('a.prev').click(function(e) {
                gallery.previousPage();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            gallery.find('a.next').click(function(e) {
                gallery.nextPage();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            /****************************************************************************************/

            /**** Functions to support integration of galleriffic with the jquery.history plugin ****/

            // PageLoad function
            // This function is called when:
            // 1. after calling $.historyInit();
            // 2. after calling $.historyLoad();
            // 3. after pushing "Go Back" button of a browser
            function pageload(hash) {
                // alert("pageload: " + hash);
                // hash doesn't contain the first # character.
                if(hash) {
                    $.galleriffic.gotoImage(hash);
                } else {
                    gallery.gotoIndex(0);
                }
            }

            // Initialize history plugin.
            // The callback is called at once by present location.hash. 
            $.historyInit(pageload, "advanced.html");

            // set onlick event for buttons using the jQuery 1.3 live method
            $("a[rel='history']").live('click', function(e) {
                if (e.button != 0) return true;

                var hash = this.href;
                hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

                // moves to a new page. 
                // pageload is called at once. 
                // hash don't contain "#", "?"
                $.historyLoad(hash);

                return false;
            });

            /****************************************************************************************/
        });
    </script>
```

This is gallerrific jquery plug in

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Probably not related but you missed http from the script include path.

Comment: @Oshawott doesn't matter, that syntax is to make the request protocol agnostic.

Comment: Instead of saying "solved", mark an answer as accepted or write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Does it just logout? or does it run `logout` function to?

Comment: @Antony Sorry I am new here I dont know how it works. I ll do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the welcome.php page (the pages are loaded in this form welcome.php?p=new_page1 welcome.php?p=new_page2 etc). The problem was a forgoten endsession() script that logged out the user in welcome.php code. I used jquery debug and I found end deleted the script. Thanks @KLK1 for the hint ;-)

Comment: So the problem had nothing to do with Internet Explorer? It doesn't make sense that it didn't work only in Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Can you publish your JS code ? I think it's about event linking event of JQuery in IE that causes this problem.

Have you something like this in your js : `.on("click", function(){...})` ?

Comment: I notice you to to debug event binding of JQuery. 3days ago, i had the same type of issue with firefox ! 
there is a lot of topic about how to debug jQuery event ;)
I'm not sure, it's just an idea

Comment: You were right. I used debug and I found the problem. It was a forgoten endsession function in the welcome page. Someone else before me put it there. No reason why. Anyway thank you very much for your support.